# permissions keep changing in git repository, anyone can tell me why?

Tags: macos, permission, git

This started happening about 2-3 weeks ago. 
I'm on Mac OS X Yosemite - 10.10.5
I have a git repository for a pretty big project ( there are three developers on the project), and every now and then folders and files that I had permission to write to get their permissions changed so I can't write to them anymore.

It is not always the same files.

I edit files using Brackets editor.

For example right now I have a path in the project resources/javascripts/external/resource_loader.js

every folder along that path has my profile with read/write permissions but when I get to the individual file it no longer has me there.

When I look at a file at the same level that I have not touched in a while it still has me as a user with read/write.

The file I can't edit has 
system - Read and Write
staff - Read only
everyone - Read only

the file I can edit has 
me - Read and Write
staff - Read only
everyone - Read only.

it's just an annoyance to have to go reset the permissions in the middle of writing something all the time.

Comment: Does anyone else use the git repo?

Comment: yes  - there are two other users. But only one of them uses it frequently. She has experienced some of the same issues I believe. She has the same setup as me. It sounds crazy but I am starting to think it has something to do with Brackets and opening a file I haven't looked at in a while without inspecting its permissions first - really I look at permissions for a bunch of files they're fine. I open the one file I haven't looked at in Brackets and it is bad. And these are also files that neither one of us has edited in a long time. And in most cases I have edited them last.

Comment: well found a situations where it did not happen with Brackets, which is nice because it was causing me to lose my sanity. Now it is just an irritating permissions thing that happens in my repository every now and then.

Comment: What are you using to interact with git? The git command in Terminal or some client?

Comment: i'm using the terminal.

Comment: I'm no longer experiencing the issue, probably because one of the developers left and the other developer only works on very specifically delineated parts of the project so our stuff does not tend to overlap.